# Is there any better way to pass the value from jsp to the servlet using <a href>

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have JSP page -

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

  <a href="http://localhost:8080/action/RegisterUser">Sample1</a>
  <a href="http://localhost:8080/action/RegisterUser?action=done">Sample2</a>
  <a href="http://localhost:8080/action/jsp/registerDone.jsp">Sample3</a>
  <a href="/action/WebContent/jsp/registerForm.jsp">Sample4</a>

</body>
</html>
```

And servlet -

```
package example;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/RegisterUser")
public class RegisterUser extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String forwardPath = null;
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if(action == null) {
            forwardPath = "/action/WebContent/jsp/registerForm.jsp";
        }

        if(action != null && action.equals("done")) {
            forwardPath = "/action/WebContent/jsp/registerDone.jsp";
        }

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(forwardPath);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

First, I want to pass a value from JSP to the Servlet.
Next, I want to make a conditional branch
Finally, I want to display the jps screen

When I click on the  tag(Sample1,Sample2,Sample4), I get a 404 error.
The error message is "/action/http://localhost:8080/action/jsp/registerForm.jsp"(if i click on the "sample1 and 2").
When i click on the Sample3, it work.
Is the PATH I specified wrong?
Please teach me.

I use...
Eclipse2020
tomcat9
Java EE

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOcO0.png)

Comment: The problem with `?action=done` is that anyone can inject that into your application.  Feels like bad practice.  I know there's better ways of doing this, but I have been away from JSPs too long to remember the details.  Might change your question to "is there a better way?"

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed the title

Answer (score 0):

I modify jsp to

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String forwardPath = null;
        String action = null;
        action = request.getParameter("action");

        if(action == null) {
            action = "miss";
            forwardPath = "registerForm.jsp";
        }

        if(action.equals("done")) {
            forwardPath = "registerDone.jsp";
        }

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(forwardPath);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
```

And modify servlet to

```
<body>

  <a href="http://localhost:8080/action/RegisterUser">Sample1</a>
  <a href="http://localhost:8080/action/RegisterUser?action=done">Sample2</a>

</body>
```

After changing the file location to
https://gyazo.com/e79a8d083e5cc0c4ebb0d398e00a17ad , it work. 
Thanks to everyone for helping me